# Swift convert Currency string to double

Tags: swift, currency, nsformatter

I have a string, `"$4,102.33"` that needs to be converted to double. This will always be US. My only way is a hack to strip out the `$` and `,` and then convert to double. Seems like `NSFormatter` only lets me convert TO a currency and not from it. Is there a built-in function or better way than just removing the `$` and `,`? prior to converting it to double?

Comment: Side note, avoid using `Double` for currency: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency

Comment: `NSNumberFormatter` will easily convert that string to a number if you set it up properly. Show your attempt use of `NSNumberFormatter` in your question.

Comment: Argh - I only saw the .string method. Didn't realize there was a .number method.  :-(

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`NumberFormatter` can convert to and from string. Also `Double` cannot represent certain numbers exactly since it's based 2. Using `Decimal` is slower but safer.

```
let str = "$4,102.33"

let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .currency

if let number = formatter.number(from: str) {
    let amount = number.decimalValue
    print(amount)
}
```

Comment: Note - If the string is always going to be formatted as USD, you will need to set the formatter's locale to `en_US`. If you don't, the string won't be parsed properly in most other locales.

Answer (score 5):

To convert from String to NSNumber for a given currency is easy:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
let number = formatter.number(from: string)
```

To get your number as a Double or as a Decimal ([preferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency?noredirect=1&lq=1)) is then direct:

```
let doubleValue = number?.doubleValue
let decimalValue = number?.decimalValue
```